# Is there any time limit for Firestore SnapshotListeners

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First, I know how to use Firestore and snapshot listeners. I am asking that I am planning to observe a document from the program to trigger some events according to it.

But I am not sure if there is a time limit for listeners to observe a doc constantly, and are there any costs for it? Because I probably let it run 7 24 without detaching listeners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there are not time limits. What more I think that listeners concept is to work 24/7.

When it comes to cost, there are no additional charges for listening, however it is important to understand costs logic. The concept of Firestore cost is based on operations called reads, writes and deletes.  From that perspective it does not matter if you are listening or getting data, only how often and how many document the app reads.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#listens) describes this:

> When you listen to the results of a query, you are charged for a read
> each time a document in the result set is added or updated. You are
> also charged for a read when a document is removed from the result set
> because the document has changed. (In contrast, when a document is
> deleted, you are not charged for a read.)
>
> Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for
> example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as
> if you had issued a brand-new query.

To sum it up, I think, yes you can setup listeners 24/7, there are no additional costs, but you will pay for document reads.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to be sure about it